# KWallet Error when attempting to decrypt the wallet ... Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: kde, gnupg

Whenever I try to open something that needs access to KWallet (e.g. Browser), this dialog box pops up:

[image: KWallet GPG Error Dialog Box]

I've read elsewhere that to fix this you need to set the `GPG_TTY` environment variable to `$(tty)`, and I've tried to put it in my `~/.profile`, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Edit: Also, I'm running Manjaro 22.0, if that helps.

Comment: It should have been set in `/etc/bash.bashrc` to `GPG_TTY="\\`tty\\`"` and exported.Please do not post images where plain text will do.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling KWallet entirely in the settings fixed the problem entirely, and all the programs that previously required KWallet still work fine...? I guess I'll take it lol

Edit: I ended up just using `gnome-keyring`.